# Filter out Google Calendar invites from people not in my contact list

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts

How do I set up a filter in Gmail account so that invitations from people not in my contact list are automatically deleted (and the event removed from my calendar)?

Answer (score 1):

As per GMail help, it seems that it is not possible to create a filter without specifying each and every email.

But, what you can do is to suggest them ...
https://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs

Comment: Do you have a link to the relevant Gmail help article?

Comment: It is not said in clear, but I deduct it from this help article : https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8870&topic=1669049